# web page displaying incorrectly on other devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I have a little problem where my web page is displaying fine on my pc screen but when i go live on my laptop or mobile phone the layout is all messed up. Does anyone know how i can fix this? Its is completely ruined in other screens and is not user friendly, but on my main computer where i was using to preview and create my website, it is basically ready.

```css
/*PLAYER PAGE*/

.container {
  padding: 40px 20px 0;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
  border-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
}

h1 span {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s;
}

.meet-the-owner h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
}

.meet-the-owner-top h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  padding: 40px;
}

.luxxreno {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  bottom: 150px;
}

.luxxreno img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}

.meet-the-owner {
  padding: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(105, 105, 105);
}

.q-l {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: right;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.questions p {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

.luxx-name {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.owner {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  color: red;
}

.luxx-socials {
  position: relative;
  left: 9px;
  top: 50px;
}

.luxx-socials ul li {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 30px;
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffd700;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.luxx-socials ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.luxx-socials ul a li:hover {
  color: red;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--
  <script>
    ScrollReveal({
      reset: true
    });
  </script>
  -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Players | LuxxMob</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/360332bae9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu-header">
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/HD_FILE (2).png" /></a>
      <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
        <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="news.html">News</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="players.html">Players</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!--END OF NAV-->

  <section class="player-bios">

    <div class="container">
      <h1>
        <span>Players</span>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="meet-the-owner-top">

      <h3>Meet the Owner</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="luxxreno">

      <img src="images/luxx.jpg">
      <div class="q-l">
        <div class="questions">
          <h2 class="luxx-name">LUXX RENO</h2>
          <h2 class="owner">OWNER</h2>
          <p>Real Name: <b>Cory George</b></p>
          <p>Online Name: <b>Luxx Reno</b></p>
          <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Duck Hunter/Super Nintendo</b></p>
          <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Fortnite</b></p>
          <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <b>Mimicry, so I'd be able to mimic and super power I see.</b></p>
          <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Billy Raffoul</b></p>
          <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Won lots of medals for swimming!</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="luxx-socials">
          <ul>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPqsHNuWTAbckHg4R3WAJIg" target=”_blank”>
              <li>487 @ YouTube</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/luxxreno/?hl=en" target=”_blank”>
              <li>2.6k @ Instagram</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/luxxreno" target=”_blank”>
              <li>3k @ Twitch</li>
            </a><br>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/LuxxReno" target=”_blank”>
              <li>2.5k @ Twitter</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@luxxxreno?lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1" target=”_blank”>
              <li>657k @ TikTok</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="meet-the-owner">

      <h3>Content Creator</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="luxxreno">

      <img src="images/abz-c.png">
      <div class="q-l">
        <div class="questions">
          <h2 class="luxx-name">ABZZINO</h2>
          <h2 class="owner">Content Creator</h2>
          <p>Real Name: <b>Abdullah Khan</b></p>
          <p>Online Name: <b>Abzzino</b></p>
          <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Call Of Duty</b></p>
          <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Call Of Duty (all of them)</b></p>
          <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <b>Flying</b></p>
          <p>Hidden Talents: <b>They're hidden for a reason.</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="luxx-socials">
          <ul>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/Abzzino/featured" target=”_blank”>
              <li>360 @ YouTube</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_abzzino_/" target=”_blank”>
              <li>193 @ Instagram</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/abzzinok" target=”_blank”>
              <li>2.6k @ Twitch</li>
            </a><br>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/_Abzzino_" target=”_blank”>
              <li>142 @ Twitter</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@abzzinoyt?lang=en" target=”_blank”>
              <li>23.6k @ TikTok</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="meet-the-owner">

      <h3>COMPETITIVE PLAYER</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="luxxreno">

      <img src="images/kyran-c.png">
      <div class="q-l">
        <div class="questions">
          <h2 class="luxx-name">KEEZO</h2>
          <h2 class="owner">COMPETITIVE PLAYER</h2>
          <p>Real Name: <b>Kyran Garden</b></p>
          <p>Online Name: <b>KEEZO</b></p>
          <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Call Of Duty 3</b></p>
          <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Warzone</b></p>
          <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <b>Flying</b></p>
          <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Drake</b></p>
          <p>Hidden Talents: <b>I'm good at football.</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="luxx-socials">
          <ul>
            <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/LKeezo" target=”_blank”>
              <li>400 @ Twitch</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/KEEZZ0" target=”_blank”>
              <li>1.2k @ Twitter</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@kkeezo?lang=en" target=”_blank”>
              <li>1.1k @ TikTok</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="meet-the-owner">

      <h3>Content Manager</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="luxxreno">

      <img src="images/brad-c.png">
      <div class="q-l">
        <div class="questions">
          <h2 class="luxx-name">SPODERBRAD</h2>
          <h2 class="owner">Content Manager</h2>
          <p>Real Name: <b>Brad</b></p>
          <p>Online Name: <b>SpoderBrad</b></p>
          <p>First Game Played as a Kid: <b>Metal Gear Solid</b></p>
          <p>Game I'm Best At: <b>Splitgate</b></p>
          <p>If You Were a Superhero, What Would Your Power Be?: <b>Honestly don’t want a super power just wanna be Iron Man.</b></p>
          <p>Favourite Artist of All Time: <b>Drake or Eminem can’t decide</b></p>
          <p>Hidden Talents: <b>Best Free Kick Taker on Twitch.</b></p>
        </div>

        <div class="luxx-socials">
          <ul>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnqgXWWmmg1F3L919lzT6aQ" target=”_blank”>
              <li>353 @ YouTube</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spoderbrad/?hl=en-gb" target=”_blank”>
              <li>115 @ Instagram</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/SpoderBrad" target=”_blank”>
              <li>2.1k @ Twitch</li>
            </a><br>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/SpoderBrad" target=”_blank”>
              <li>392 @ Twitter</li>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@spoderbrad?lang=en" target=”_blank”>
              <li>60k @ TikTok</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>


  <!--FOOTER-->

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-headers">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="news.html">News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="players.html">Players</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="foot-logo">
      <img src="images/HD_FILE (2).png" />

    </div>
    <div class="socials">

      <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@luxxmob?lang=en"> <i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/LuxxMob"> <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/TheLuxxMob/"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
      <h4>&copy 2021 LuxxMob</h4>
      <h4>Made with &#10084 by <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@truechow?lang=en">@truechow</a></h4>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!--
  <script>
    ScrollReveal().reveal('footer', {
      duration: 2000
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.luxxreno', {
      duration: 2000
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.header');
  </script>
  <script>
    ScrollReveal(options);
  </script>
-->

</body>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to demonstrate the problem and be much more clear about what's not working as you'd like. "All messed up" isn't a problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of random things in your css that I don't know why they're there.  `max-width: 2000px`, why is this 2000 pixels, it would be way too much for most phones and screens (perhaps there's a reason like the player map being large, I dunno).  `overflow: hidden`, why is there an overflow on a h1 tag.  `border-width: 100%`, why are you setting border widths to 100%.  `margin: 0 auto` why is there a margin auto on a 2000px wide container, it'll never be the center of anything.  `position: relative`, why is everything relative.  There's a bunch of random CSS that I don't know what it's doing or why it's there (it shouldn't be).

Along with that you shouldn't ever use pixels for fonts, it won't scale on a mobile phone so your text (and containers containing text) will get messed up.  Use `font-size: 100%` on the `html` container and then use `font-size: 1rem // or 1.2 or 1.4` on anything else so you scale everything according to root.

Along with that you've used pixels everywhere to define borders/tops/alignment, which will almost never work out (unless you're just lucky).  You should be using `flex` for page layout and pixels if you want to define specific containers.  You've not shown body and the main page CSS but from container I can see you've not used that.  You should have:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Or something similar for your page layout.  You don't need any @media stuff for that because flex will work correctly across all devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your webpage is not responsive. An easy fix is to always use percentages instead of specific pixels to position items.

eg top: 5% instead of top: 15px

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have to use media queries to make your website responsive on all devices.
Check it out here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries

Another tip is not to use only pixels as a unit of measurement, also use 'em', 'rem', vw (for the font) and '%'

Check it out here too:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp